# Need a Stored Procedure/Query which will return result in MS SQL from Existing Table

Tags: sql, linq, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have table structure like below.

[image: Exiting table]

Required following output from existing Table by running Query:

[image: Required output by running Query]

Required in time and out time from one single table base on 1st entry on that date and location and last entry on date and location.

[image: Combined Image for Data and Result]

Comment: I don't get your question.  The first two rows in the first result set have the same date and location, so according to your description, they should be combined.

Comment: 1st table is data captured.